# Read the last data and generate alphanumeric employee number

Tags: php

I have a column in my database employee number and data which is ACZ2020000. When I add an employee, the generated employee number is ACZ2020002. How can I generate the ACZ2020001? Help me, please. Thanks so much, guys.

This what I did:

```
public function generate_employee_id() {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows FROM tbl_accounts");
    $row = $query->fetch_object();
    $number = $row->num_rows;
    ++$number;
       
    $len = strlen($number);
    for($i = $len; $i < 3; ++$i) {
        $number = '0' . $number;
    }

    $employee_number = 'ACZ'. date("Y") . $number;

    echo json_encode(['employee_number' => $employee_number]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the highest number, something that doesn't have anything to do with the number of rows. If I understood the rules, you can do this to get the numbers already used:

```
SELECT employee_id, CAST(SUBSTR(employee_id, 5) AS signed) -- MySQL flavour
FROM tbl_accounts
WHERE employee_id LIKE 'ACZ20%'
```

... and good old `MAX()` to grab the latest:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTR(employee_id, 5) AS SIGNED)) + 1 AS next
FROM tbl_accounts
WHERE employee_id LIKE 'ACZ20%'
```

Said that, beware of potential issues caused by concurrent accesses!

Comment: Thanks for this! But the employee number I got is like this ACZ202020001. I want the employee number like this: ACZ2020001. Any help?

Comment: The 5 in substr() are the leading characters to skip (the length of `ACZ20`). Just tweak accordingly for full 4-digit years.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the *best* answer here would be to recommend *not* trying to manage your employee number sequence from your PHP application.  Instead, let your database do that heavy lifting by way of an auto increment column or something similar.  Note that if all employee numbers be prefaced by `ACZ`, then you really only need a way to generate a sequence, and this is something that databases are reasonably good at doing.

Comment: This is by far the most sensible approach. It's simple, robust and also deals gracefully with employee removals (it won't reuse codes).